# Why Does boost::sort deduce a const range& input type?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

When I try to pass the result of a nested `boost::accumulate` algorithm (where the result is a `std::vector`) into `boost::sort`, the compiler deduces that the input of `boost::sort` is a `const std::vector&` even though it correctly deduces the return type of `boost::accumulate` to be `std::vector`. Why is that? The code below does not compile, complaining about `operator=` being undefined for `resultT`.

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/copy_n.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp>
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

struct resultT
{
    std::string name;
    double quantity;
};

auto operator<(const resultT& lhs, const resultT& rhs) -> bool
{
    return std::tie(lhs.quantity, lhs.name)
        < std::tie(rhs.quantity, rhs.name);
}

auto operator>(const resultT& lhs, const resultT& rhs) -> bool
{
    return rhs < lhs;
}

auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const resultT& row) -> std::ostream&
{
    os << row.name << '\t' << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed << row.quantity;
    return os;
}

template<typename T>
auto calculate(const T& in) -> double
{
    //a stand-in for real operations on T--not important to the example
    return in.second;
}

using resultContainer = std::vector<resultT>;

template<typename QuantityT>
auto add(resultContainer& accumulated, const QuantityT& next) -> resultContainer&
{
    auto accumulated_itr{boost::find_if(accumulated, [&next](const resultT& in) -> bool
    {
        return in.name == next.second.first;
    })};

    if (accumulated_itr == std::end(accumulated))
    {
        accumulated.emplace_back(resultT{next.second.first, calculate(next.second)});
    }
    else
    {
        accumulated_itr->quantity += calculate(next.second);
    }

    return accumulated;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    using InnerT = std::pair<int, std::pair<std::string, int>>;
    using OuterT = std::pair<char, std::pair<std::string, int>>;
    auto addInnerOne{[](resultContainer& accumulated, const InnerT& next) { return add<InnerT>(accumulated, next); }};
    auto addOuterOne{[](resultContainer& accumulated, const OuterT& next) { return add<OuterT>(accumulated, next); }};

    auto InnerOne{std::unordered_multimap<int, std::pair<std::string, int>>
    {
        {0, {"hi", 1}}
        , {1, {"ho", 5}}
        , {2, {"hi", 7}}
        , {3, {"ho", 7}}
        , {4, {"hey", 9}}
        , {5, {"fiddle", 11}}
        , {6, {"hey", 11}}
        , {7, {"ho", 3}}
    }};
    auto OuterOne{std::unordered_map<char, std::pair<std::string, int>>
    {
        {'A', {"hi", 1}}
        , {'B', {"ho", 5}}
        , {'C', {"hi", 7}}
        , {'D', {"ho", 7}}
        , {'E', {"hey", 9}}
        , {'F', {"diddle", 21}}
        , {'G', {"hey", 5}}
        , {'H', {"ho", 3}}
    }};

    boost::copy_n(
        boost::sort(
            boost::accumulate(OuterOne
                              , boost::accumulate(InnerOne
                                                  , resultContainer{}
                                                  , addInnerOne)
                              , addOuterOne)
                    , std::greater<resultT>())
        , 5
        , std::ostream_iterator<resultT>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

[Here you can see the issue live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04b7a70653e31a05).

---

Here is a simple fix that goes around the problem. I already have this fix--I want to know why I needed this workaround in the first place:

```
auto quant{   //quant's type is correctly deduced to be std::vector
    boost::accumulate(OuterOne
                      , boost::accumulate(InnerOne
                                          , resultContainer{}
                                          , addInnerOne)
                      , addOuterOne)};

boost::copy_n(
    boost::sort(quant
                , std::greater<resultT>())
    , 5
    , std::ostream_iterator<resultT>(std::cout, "\n"));

return 0;
```

[Here is the fix live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90ad13adedfb602f).

Comment: because `quant` is an lvalue, while the result of `accumulate` is a prvalue. why do you think `accumulate` returns `vector<>&` ?

Comment: Hmm, even if I pass in an empty lvalue to accumulate, instead of using an rvalue like I did above? (I tried constructing an empty lvalue and passing that in--didn't work).

I think I assumed that it would return a `vector<>&` because that's the type I was using in all of my operators. Silly assumption, and one that is *not* backed up by any of the type deduction in my IDE. I removed the `&` from the question text.

Comment: *"even if I pass in an empty lvalue to accumulate, instead of using an rvalue like I did above?"* accumulate returns always a prvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boost::accumulate`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/numeric/accumulate.html) is defined as follows:

```
template<
    class SinglePassRange,
    class Value,
    class BinaryOperation
    >
Value accumulate(const SinglePassRange& source_rng,
                 Value init,
                 BinaryOperation op);
```

That is, it returns a prvalue of a type deduced for `Value` (in your case `std::vector<resultT>`), thus it cannot be bound by a non-const lvalue reference. Given two overloads of [`boost::sort`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html):

```
template<class RandomAccessRange>
RandomAccessRange& sort(RandomAccessRange& rng);

template<class RandomAccessRange>
const RandomAccessRange& sort(const RandomAccessRange& rng);
```

in both cases `RandomAccessRange` is deduced as `std::vector<resultT>`, but only the latter is viable for call `sort(accumulate(..., vector<resultT>{}, ...))`.

By first assigning the returned value of `boost::accumulate` to variable `quant`, an expression involving this name is, in turn, a non-const lvalue, so it is bound by the overload you want.

Comment: Is there anyway to modify the return type of accumulate? Perhaps by explicitly specifying the type of `Value` to be a reference?

Comment: @caps it doesn't seem reasonable, you could create a reference wrapper than transforms a prvalue into an lvalue reference, but that's ugly